# Best Practices for Setup and Management of an Open Source Project

Tags: open-source, project-management, installation

Later this year I want to release a PHP framework that I've been working on as open source. I do use source control (SVN), but it's on an extremely limited basis. I'm self-taught, I develop by myself and don't have the experience of working with large teams. I have some ideas about what can help make a project successful, but I'm fuzzy on some of the details. Since it's not yet released, I want to do everything I can to set up the right infrastructure from the beginning. What do I need to know in order to setup and manage a successful project?

Some ideas that I have to make it successful (beyond marketing it):

- Good documentation and tutorials
- Automated unit tests and builds to
  push update to the website
- A clear roadmap
- Bug Tracking integrated with the
  source control
- A style guide to keep the code
  consistent
- A forum for the community to get
  support, share ideas, etc.
- A good example application built with
  the framework
- A blog to keep the community informed
- Maintaining backwards compatibility
  wherever possible

Some of my questions:

- How do I setup and automate a one
  step submit-test-commit-generate API
  docs-push update to website process? **Edit**: Would Ant or Maven be good candidates for this? If so, do you know of any resources for setting up a PHP project using them?
- How do I handle (technically)
  submissions from other users? How can
  I ensure that those submissions must
  be approved before being integrated?
- What are some of the pitfalls that
  can be avoided in terms of the
  project community? I'd prefer to have
  it be as friendly and helpful as
  possible without a lot of drama.

I'd love to learn from your experience on any of these points. If you think I'm missing anything big, please share that as well. Any resources (preferably geared toward a beginner) that you could point me towards would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One question at a time is a good idea here.

Comment: At this point, the first question about setup of an automatic system is probably my main concern.

Comment: shameless plug: http://www.openprojectguide.org/ I am writing some blog posts there regarding the start and "maintenance" of open source projects mostly from a people standpoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just getting started in community projects, but I'll give you some advice on what I know.

> How do I setup and automate a one step submit-test-commit-generate API docs-push update to website process?

I've never implemented it as one process. You could just have a checklist, and possibly even create some scripts to do certain tasks. I've never worked with any source control that automates the uploading and such to be done by a script. Most of the time, there is some web interaction to be involved.

You don't want to push API changes until it's an official release.

**EDIT: Working Environment**

For PHP, most of the time, I either edit directly on the server and test it there, using a *beta.example.com*, or similar, before pushing to example.com. You could also set up an web environment on your home PC (using XAMPP for Windows, or the standard LAMP installation on Linux). You would probably just use a mirror of your repository here, so you'd do `svn commit`, or whichever is appropriate for the VCS or DVCS you choose.

The fun part is testing this with different PHP versions. I've not done this myself, but you could probably use a .htaccess file to run a different PHP binary in order to test it out. I'm not really sure what the best option is for this is.

I've not done much with API, as I've never created a library, but just doing a quick search I found http://www.phpdoc.org/. It looks like a mature project, so that might be a starting point.

As far as creating releases go, I generally create a script that only includes the files that are part of the distribution (it will filter out any VCS files, and anything that you don't want in the distributed file). You could write a script around `find` on linux (which is what I do most of the time), or there may be other better options.

> How do I handle (technically) submissions from other users? How can I ensure that those submissions must be approved before being integrated?

This is mostly handled by the bug tracker, and limited access in the Version Control System. Usually, you, and the people you allow, can commit to the VCS. Other users can submit patches, but then you might have someone review the patch, test the patch, and commit. You could split these tasks up as a team, or assign a patch to one person and have them do it all.

> What are some of the pitfalls that can be avoided in terms of the project community? I'd prefer to have it be as friendly and helpful as possible without a lot of drama.

I would just make sure to keep it as positive as possible with the project members and community. There's going to be some disagreements, and it will drive a few people away, but as long as you have a stable product that meets the needs of most people, I think that's all that anyone can expect.

Comment: Good point on the API docs. Perhaps wanting to do all of it in one step is too much to hope for, but could you go into more detail on how you've done it in multiple steps? What tools did you use, etc.?

Comment: See my "Working Environment" section above.

Answer (score 5):

One minor suggestion that's worked well for me: start using first-person *plural* pronouns, rather than singular ones.  That is, talk about "we" and "us" rather than "I" and "me."  It encourages other people to participate when they feel like part of team, rather than when they feel like they're contributing your own self-aggrandizement.

Comment: Seems weird that this was an accepted answer to me. It only answered one question, and it didn't even answer it completely. Oh well, I won't hold a grudge *(grumbles)* :)

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing you have to do is to attract users. Without users, you won't get any contributions and developers helping you out. Because developers are users first, and then they decide to extend/fix something they use and might become contributors.

So to get users, you should consider

- describe what your framework does in one or two sentences at the top of your project page
- mention how your framework can be used and for what, what situations it is most useful for
- add a lot of examples on how to use it
- mention whether your framework is stable, beta or alpha. That's important because user need to know that before they start using it
- also mention whether you want to keep improving it and keep working on it - most users don't want to use a framework that's abandoned (also keep in mind that a lot of users check your commits to see whether you really are working on it - if your last commit to the repository was months ago then you're not really working on it, so cheating isn't possible)

If you got all this, and people start submitting patches, you can use a patch tool to apply those to your source. Depending on your version control system, you can either use the GNU patch, a diff/patch tool that comes with your version control or maybe even a GUI tool that helps you with this. SVN doesn't have a patch tool (yet), but 'svn diff' will create a patchfile which you can then apply with the GNU patch tool, or in case you're using TortoiseSVN, right-drag the patchfile to your working copy and have TortoiseMerge apply it for you.

And on how to best deal with the community:

- answer questions in time, don't wait more than two or three days to answer questions
- try to be nice, even with upset and angry people. Only if they keep bothering tell them to (still in a nice way if possible) go elsewhere
- always keep discussions about the project on a mailing list. You don't want to repeat the same discussions over and over again - if you have a mailing list, just point users to the archives before the discussion starts all over again

And you should watch the talk "[How Open Source Projects Survive Poisonous People (And You Can Too)](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4216011961522818645&q=ben+collins-sussman&pr=goog-sl)" - it's really good and tells you a lot on how to deal not just with 'poisonous people' but also how to deal with all people involved in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that you should make it as easy as possible for your users to get the whole thing running and modify the code - these 'power users' can be 'converted' into developers or at least people who send smaller patches.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to do it all yourself - for open source projects there are several hosting providers that solve most of the problems. I recommend codeplex or google code.

Setting up build scripts will depend a certain amount on what platform you set up, but in general it's easy to add any tool you want into the script once you start using any sort of build script.

If you really need the one step process you describe, you need a build server. I use TeamCity, which I have set up to watch for any changes in svn and trigger build/test whenever something is checked in. The build server will generally be able to perform any steps that you put into the build script.

Comment: TeamCity looks intriguing. Do you use it for a PHP project? Do you know of anything similar that I could compare it to?

Comment: I haven't used it for php, but it's not language specific. It has a command line runner as well as msbuild, ant etc, so as long as you have some sort of build script to run on the server it will work. 

CruiseControl is also quite popular, though I haven't worked with it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Read up on [Git](http://git-scm.com/) as an alternative to SVN**

- free public repository/bug tracker/wiki/fork-enabled community in [Github](http://github.com) (which hosts [symfony](http://github.com/symfony/symfony) and [PHPUnit](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) amongst others)
- "*How do I handle (technically) submissions from other users? How can I ensure that those submissions must be approved before being integrated?*" - with Git, pull what you/your closest team finds most interesting to the master branch

**Consistent API**

- be inspired of other public API:s
- only change in major versions
- guessable

**Interesting for both users & developers**

- clear goal (your roadmap - excellent)
- useful, contra everything else available
- easy to use, but still not easy-enough-to-write/maintain-yourself

You could check out either Ant or Phing to build your project. Include [CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) in the build and you'll save time checking for basic formatting errors/differences.

These are all technical tips, about the soft part... treat humans with respect, a lot of interest and be *overly* excited about their contributions and make them feel that they're not wasting their time. That would appeal to me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Karl Fogel's book on [Producing Open Source Software](http://producingoss.com/). It probably has everything that you asked.

You should also plan for engaging the community. I'd recommend reading Jono Bacon's The Art of Community [http://www.artofcommunityonline.org/].

Answer (score 0):

You have a great set of ideas to start. You might have to start by trimming them down! Ask yourself what's necessary for a first release.

1. For automating the builds and tests, the scripting can be done with ant, maven or [phing](http://phing.info/trac/) for PHP projects.
2. You'll probably need a host so you can demo the product. For PHP that is pretty easy to find.
3. You need an open source hosting provider-- especially [github](http://github.com) (but also google code, source forge, etc). Github provides bug tracking, default licenses, blog and great mechanisms for accepting changes from the community. Built on git, it facilitates distributed projects quite well.

Although it's good to have a one-step build and install in place, automating integration of others changes probably isn't important (or desirable) off the bat.

Good luck!